# can't insert in mySQL . Registration form

Tags: php, mysql

I had a working registration form, but i somehow messed it up.
I get this error in my move-upload line, and i really don't know how to fix it because it was working and i didn't change that line in particular.

> Parse error : syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in
>   /home/nel/public_html/test/process.php on line 18

```
    <?php
    include "config.php";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$school= $_POST['school'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$grad_year = $_POST['gradYear'];
$hardware = $_POST['hardware'];
$type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];

if(empty($name) || empty($school) || empty($email) || empty($grad_year) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
   echo "You did not fill out the required fields correctly. Please try again!";
}
else{
$insert = "INSERT INTO hackers VALUES('$name','$email','$school','$grad_year’,’$hardware’)”;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home/nel/resumes/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 

echo "Thank you for registering!”;

echo $name= $_Files['file']['name'];

    $conn->query($insert);
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide table schema of your hackers table.

Comment: you are using `’` instead of `'` (single quote) also `”` instead of `"` double quote in insert query and thank you message.

Comment: At the end of you $insert variable you mistyped the double quote : replace it by a regular one...

Comment: I wonder how things like these can happen. Do people use Word for programming?

Answer (score 2):

You have use ticks instead of single quotes here `'$grad_year’,’$hardware’`. change it and your errors should gone.

Also you should use prepared statement. It is much more safety and readable.

Answer (score 0):

do changes as below, also see my comment

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO hackers VALUES('$name','$email','$school','$grad_year','$hardware')"; // change here 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home/nel/resumes/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 

echo "Thank you for registering!"; // change here
```